# How to estimate the power consumption of a motor when running at low load

Tags: power, motor, three-phase, power-factor-correction

I am trying to calculate the electrical power cost-saving of reducing the amount of time a machine runs idle (when the motor is running unloaded).

From the meter data, the amps when idling is about 20% of full-load amps.

So, the real power consumption (for 3-phase motor) is given by:

```
power_consumption = voltage*fla*0.01*full_load_amps*np.sqrt(3)*power_factor
```

(where `fla = 20`)

But I also know the PF will be very low (24% we think) so does this mean that the power consumption is also not that high and therefore there is very little saving?

Intuitively I suspect not, since motor efficiency will be very low power will be being lost somewhere, maybe in the distribution system.

How do I estimate the actual power cost (at the utility meter) of this idling machine?

Comment: You said it yourself, PF is very low at light load. Measure the _active_ power consumption or estimate it.

Comment: Thanks @winny.  Can you clarify how I calculate that?  Is active power different from real power (which is what I calculated isn't it)?

Comment: Same thing, different name. “Real” is a bit nonstandard. If you know the inductance, you can back calculate active power from just current measurement to perhaps an acceptable degree if you are interested. As for cost, consumers don’t normally pay for reactive power (bad PF), but this varies. Industries normally do pay for it.

Comment: So, just to confirm, my equation in the question is the correct way to calculate the power-saving of shutting off this idling machine.

Comment: Your calculation is correct, assuming the power factor and current are correct.

Comment: so saving 4.8% of FL

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks.  Not quite the energy-saving I was hoping for...